# Marked Items in Horizontal Chart matching with created details visualization

Tags: javascript, ironpython, spotfire

I have a horizontal bar contains top 25 defect rate and also created a details visualization using cross table. When i marked the top 1 the details like model and qty populate and shown in cross table. My requirements is to count/sum all records with marked and unmarked and use as multiplier to the qty to get the d rate the cross table.

I try this approached dynamically Sum(case  when [XXX]="XXX" then 1 end) OVER (All([Axis.Rows])) as [Overall Total] but the result is the total qty that are marked are the one displayed or captured. Is there any idea on how to do this using over function or other approached. Thank you in advance.

[image: Sample Main and Details Visualization]

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is that the Details Visualization doesn't actually contain all of the data, just what's marked.  The Over Function can only process what's inside the actual visualization, not the entire data table.  Remove the filter by rows marked, and adjust from there.
If that's not the issue, I think you need to provide more information -- please provide a sample of your columns/data and what you'd *like* to see, if everything's working correctly.

Comment: Yes Chelsea, it contains only the marked data of details visualization. i got only the qty which is Ok but i need to multiply the qty of detail visualization to the overall total to get the rate %. Is there any alternative using scripting?

Comment: Please find above the sample screen shot. select the top 1 in main visualization and populate the data to details visualization. it shows only the qty. Need the overall count which i would like to multiply to qty to get the rate% per category or it depend on values the i choose from the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks Chelsea. I got it. my concern is how can i passed the selected item (description)

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is to grab the description of your marked data when you press a button, the general IronPython Script is here:

```
rowIndexSet=Document.ActiveMarkingSelectionReference.GetSelection(Document.Data.Tables["DataTableName"]).AsIndexSet()

if rowIndexSet.IsEmpty != True:
    SelectedDesc = Document.Data.Tables["DataTableName"].Columns["Description"].RowValues.GetFormattedValue(rowIndexSet.First)
    Document.Properties["PropertyName"] = SelectedDesc
```

<sub>Please note that this will only grab the first marked value, which sounds sufficient for your use case.</sub>

You can then throw this Document Property in your over custom expression as per usual

```
([description] ='${PropertyName}')
```